# Datamaps are showing small size map of India

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I am trying to create a map with datamap and d3 js. But its showing map in reverse and very small in size. How can I resolve this. Sharing the JS fiddle for the same.

```
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/master/dist/datamaps.ind.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>

var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('container'),
  scope: 'ind'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bxp9e9j1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell where is the center and the projection. Add this to your code:

```
  setProjection: function(element) {
    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
      .center([80, 25])
      .scale(600)
      .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
    var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);
    return {path: path, projection: projection};
  }
```

**Center of India**: 20.5937° N, 78.9629° E

Complete code:

```
var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('container'),
  scope: 'ind',
  setProjection: function(element) {
    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
      .center([80, 25])
      .scale(600)
      .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
    var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

    return {path: path, projection: projection};
  }
});
```

Tip: you can change Projection type to: **Mercator**

```
projection: 'mercator',
```

that give you a flat map intead of rounded globe type.

Hope this help