# Datamaps not displaying in my browser

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to work with d3.js to create a map using [datamaps.github.io](http://datamaps.github.io/) and the map is not displaying. I am attaching the code because I need some help to resolve this challenge... I have actually followed this solution on stackoverflow  [Datamaps are showing small size map of India](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642737/datamaps-are-showing-small-size-map-of-india) and I am still not able to resolve it...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="topojson.min.js"></script>
    <script src="datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var map = new Datamap({
            element: document.getElementById('container'),
            scope: 'world'
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @GerardoFurtado — You changed the code to add an onload event handler function when you copied it to JS Fiddle.

Comment: @Quentin Of course, the script is in the <head>... where is **my** head?

Comment: @Quentin can u share the link where this question was asked since u marked this as a duplicate

Comment: @odins — There's a big yellow box at the top of the page

Comment: @Quentin ok, thanks problem solved...now i understand the onload handler suggestion thanks also Gerardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to include the scripts the right way. are they locally?

Here is a working jsfiddle referencing the libraries from a remote server:

https://jsfiddle.net/khphaLow/

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="//datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js?v=1"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You changed the code to add an onload event handler function when you copied it to JS Fiddle.

Comment: @mila_frerichs yes the scripts are local

Comment: @Quentin not on purpose, but it does not change the answer.

Comment: @mila_frerichs — Adding the onload handler *solves the problem* that the person asking the question definitely has. The answer is guessing about what the problem might be without any real evidence. It is possible that the OP *also* has that problem, but given that there is a real problem expressed in the code, that means the answer is probably wrong.